# .ucode driver not load in Debian

Tags: debian, drivers, firmware, iwlwifi

I put my .ucode file in /lib/firmware folder. On boot Debian write me:

```
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.215242] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x22983f10a64, max_idle_ns: 440795218721 ns
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216451] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216494] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216505] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-20.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216546] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-20.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216554] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216592] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-19.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216600] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216640] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-18.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216648] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216684] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-17.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216692] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216730] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216737] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-15.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216769] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-15.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216777] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-14.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216820] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-14.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216830] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode (-2)
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216867] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 22 22:32:28 LionZXY-debian kernel: [    2.216869] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
```

Exit `modinfo iwlwifi`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.7.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <linuxwifi@intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-IWL6000G2B_UCODE_API_MAX.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000C--21.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-lc-a0--21.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9260-th-a0-jf-a0--21.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-9000-pu-a0-lc-a0--21.ucode
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.7.0-1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size:amsdu size 0:4K 1:8K 2:12K (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
parm:           d0i3_timeout:Timeout to D0i3 entry when idle (ms) (uint)
parm:           disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
```

My Linux version:

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.7.0-1-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 5.4.1 20160904 (Debian 5.4.1-2) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.7.8-1 (2016-10-19)
```

I can't enable WiFi. 
[image]
Download driver from git.kernel.org (I need reputation to post more than 2 links)

All log and other things you can find [here](https://yadi.sk/d/953-qPunxR2H6).

Big thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical for the std deb kernel, it will look for a version and fail to load it until it finds a valid one and it will load that one.

for example in my log file;

Oct 23 16:39:43 mike-laptop4 kernel: [    7.432898] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Oct 23 16:39:43 mike-laptop4 kernel: [    7.432921] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2

(I have iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode but not 23 or 24 in my firmware directory)

so, for some reason if your wifi is not loading it's not finding the correct firmware version.

I'd suggest checking kernel wifi for a firmware download.

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

you can run lspci to check your wifi chip, then you can download the appropriate firmware blob based off your kernel version and wifi card.

also there are some good tips there regarding power management.

Comment: ps, double check in lspci, but it looks like you want this one: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-8000-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz